# How can I fix 'ValueError: a cannot be empty' when plotting cross-correlation as a subplot in Python?

Tags: python

I require to plot the results of cross-correlation as a subplot (3_by_3), but output show an error
"ValueError: a cannot be empty".
I attempt with multiple ways but still unable to fix this. May someone suggest how can i fix this issue.

Here is what i did (using a sample data set)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

rows,cols = 540,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('1975-01-01', periods=rows, freq='MS') 
tim=pd.to_datetime(tidx)
df_t=pd.DataFrame(tim, columns=['tim']) # time series 
df_d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b']) # data set 
df_f=pd.concat([df_t, df_d], axis=1) # final dataframe 
t1_a=df_f['tim'].iloc[0]
N=np.linspace(0, 540, 10)
M=np.arange(9)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True,squeeze=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)

T=('[a:1975-1980]', '[b:1980-1985]', '[c:1985-1990]', '[d:1990-1995]', '[e:1995-2000]', '[f:2000-2005]', '[g:2005-2010]', '[h:2010-2015]', '[i:2015-2020]')

for i, j, k in zip(N, M, T):
    
    t2_a=t1_a + relativedelta(months=i)
    t3_a=t1_a + relativedelta(months=i+60)
    sub=df_f[(df_f.tim>=t2_a) & (df_f.tim<t3_a)]
    t1_b=sub['tim'].iloc[0]
    ax=axes.flatten()[j]
    lag=[]
    cr=[]
    for m in range(0, 60, 6):
        t2_b=t1_b + relativedelta(months=m)
        t3_b=t1_b + relativedelta(months=m+12)
        sub_b=sub[(sub.tim>=t2_b) & (sub.tim<t3_b)]
        w_sub=sub_b[['a', 'b']]
        e_sub=sub_b[['a', 'b']]
        wl=w_sub['a'] - np.mean(w_sub['a'])
        eq=e_sub['b']- np.mean(e_sub['b'])
        wl=wl/np.max(wl)
        eq=eq/np.max(eq)
        corr= scipy.signal.correlate(wl-np.mean(wl), eq-np.mean(eq), mode=str(mode), method=str(method))
        lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(wl), len(eq), mode=str(mode))
        cr.append(corr)
        lag.append(lag)
        
    cc=pd.DataFrame(cr)
    ccc=np.mean(cc)
    lll=pd.DataFrame(lag)
    lll=np.mean(lll)
    ax.plot(lll, ccc, linewidth=1.0, color='black') 
    ax.text(0, 0.6, k, fontsize=14)
    fig.tight_layout()

#fig.savefig('Example.jpg', dpi=500)
```

Comment: Which line gets the error?  You should show the whole traceback.

Answer (score 0):

There was a very minor error. I already fixed and here is the answer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

rows,cols = 540,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('1975-01-01', periods=rows, freq='MS') 
tim=pd.to_datetime(tidx)
df_t=pd.DataFrame(tim, columns=['tim']) # time series 
df_d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b']) # data set 
df_f=pd.concat([df_t, df_d], axis=1) # final dataframe 
t1_a=df_f['tim'].iloc[0]
N=np.linspace(0, 540, 10)
M=np.arange(9)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True,squeeze=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)

T=('[a:1975-1980]', '[b:1980-1985]', '[c:1985-1990]', '[d:1990-1995]', '[e:1995-2000]', '[f:2000-2005]', '[g:2005-2010]', '[h:2010-2015]', '[i:2015-2020]')

for i, j, k in zip(N, M, T):
    
    t2_a=t1_a + relativedelta(months=i)
    t3_a=t1_a + relativedelta(months=i+60)
    sub=df_f[(df_f.tim>=t2_a) & (df_f.tim<t3_a)]
    t1_b=sub['tim'].iloc[0]
    ax=axes.flatten()[j]
    lag=[]
    cr=[]
    for m in range(0, 60, 6):
        t2_b=t1_b + relativedelta(months=m)
        t3_b=t1_b + relativedelta(months=m+12)
        sub_b=sub[(sub.tim>=t2_b) & (sub.tim<t3_b)]
        w_sub=sub_b[['a', 'b']]
        e_sub=sub_b[['a', 'b']]
        wl=w_sub['a'] - np.mean(w_sub['a'])
        eq=e_sub['b']- np.mean(e_sub['b'])
        wl=wl/np.max(wl)
        eq=eq/np.max(eq)
        corr= scipy.signal.correlate(wl-np.mean(wl), eq-np.mean(eq), mode=str(mode), method=str(method))
        lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(wl), len(eq), mode=str(mode))
        cr.append(corr)
        lag.append(lags)
        
    cc=pd.DataFrame(cr)
    ccc=np.mean(cc)
    lll=pd.DataFrame(lag)
    lll=np.mean(lll)
    ax.plot(lll, ccc, linewidth=1.0, color='black') 
    ax.text(0, 0.6, k, fontsize=14)
    fig.tight_layout()

#fig.savefig('Example.jpg', dpi=500)
```